# validate_uniqueness_of and indexes on mysql

Tags: activerecord, ruby-on-rails-3.2

I wrote the following migration:

```
class AddValidationsToAnimals < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    add_index :animals, [:name, :user_id], :unique => true
  end
end
```

Ok. Then, in my model, I add the following validation:

```
validates_uniqueness_of :name, :scope => :user_id
```

When I try to add a registry that will hurt this rule, unless get a pretty message in my view, I got a `RecordNotUnique` Exception.

Why? How can I fix that?

Thanks in advance.

---

```
  def create
    @animal = current_user.animals.new(params[:animal])
    @animal.valid?
    respond_to do |format|
      if @animal.save
        format.html { redirect_to @animal, notice: 'Animal registrado com sucesso.' }
        format.json { render json: @animal, status: :created, location: @animal }
      else
        format.html { render action: "new" }
        format.json { render json: @animal.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please paste your method code here. Is it a common `object.save`? Try to call `object.valid?` before and check if it's returning `false`.

Comment: I added the save method in the question. After adding a @animal.valid? before save, it works. The question that stills is why rails is not validating it?